# How to deploy a Laravel web app with Sail, including a Vue container with HTTPS and PWA configuration?

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js, deployment

I'm facing challenges while trying to deploy my Laravel web app using Sail. My docker-compose file is set up with Laravel services, but I also want to include a Vue container that has a volume in a "frontend" folder located in the root directory.

This is my docker compose file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
            - '${LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT:-6001}:6001'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - mailpit
            - selenium
            - phpmyadmin
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    phpmyadmin:
      image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
      ports:
        - 8080:80
      networks:
        - sail
      environment:
        - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - redis-cli
                - ping
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-meilisearch:/meili_data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - wget
                - '--no-verbose'
                - '--spider'
                - 'http://localhost:7700/health'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailpit:
        image: 'axllent/mailpit:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
    sail-meilisearch:
        driver: local
```

The problem arises when I configure my Vue project to be accessed via HTTPS, using valid keys and certificates. I'm unsure about the correct deployment process for this setup.

While attempting to access the Vue container locally, I encountered the error message "connection was reset." I suspect it's due to the Vue instance having HTTPS configured.

Also, my vue project is configured so that it can be installed as a PWA, could it be affected when deploying it with docker because I'm not taking something into account? I have a domain purchased and a validated certificate but I'm not sure where I should put it or configure it.

I appreciate any guidance and insights into resolving these challenges. Thank you for your assistance!

Thank you very much for your attention.

I've come across suggestions of using a reverse proxy like Nginx, but I lack knowledge of its configuration and how it fits into the setup.

My idea is that when deploying I just have to upload my project files next to the docker compose and launch it, instead of having frontend and backend deployed separately. However, I may be misunderstanding the entire process, and I'm open to clarifications.

My `vite.config.ts` (here is where I configured the https connection):

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa'
import mkcert from 'vite-plugin-mkcert'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host:true,
    port:3000, // This is the port that Docker uses
    https: {
      key: './private.key',
      cert: './certificate.crt'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    VitePWA({
      manifest: {
        icons:[
          {
          src: "/icons/logo.png",
          sizes: '512x512',
          type: 'image/png',
          purpose: 'any maskable'
          }
        ],
      },
      registerType: 'autoUpdate'
    }),
    mkcert()
  
  ],
    
})
```

And this is the screenshot of the error trying to access the frontend on my laptop (connected through the same router net):

[Browser error when I try to access the frontend with another laptop in the same network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbP4R.jpg)

Comment: You will need to share what config you have on Vue setup so it uses HTTPS and gives you issues. You should not need to setup anything, as doing a request should be on the same domain, you do not require certificates or anything on the frontend, could you show us an example of code that is failing, share the error you can see in the network tab of your browser's console, and what config you have that it is making it failing on HTTP(S)

Comment: I just tried to recreate the error to put screenshots and suddenly I can access the frontend without problem locally.... However, when trying to log in with my mobile or my laptop I get the same error "The connection was reset". I will update my answer with more info and screenshots. If I don't need any certificates on my frontend, then where should I put them?

Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Now I have more questions than answers, when you say deploy, are you saying "production"? If it is a no, then of course the project will not exactly work locally, as you would also have to open ports on the hosting machine, and more config like it has to use LAN IP, not `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` or whatever you have (so assets are accessible). Show a URL of one file not working, please. And add a little bit more info

Comment: I do not see the port 3000 exposed on docker, so it would never be reachable on your LAN IP

Comment: Indeed when I say deploy I meant to refer to production, sorry to have caused confusion .... I have edited the configuration of my docker compose with a container called "vue" to which I have assigned port 3000, but when I try to access in LAN with other device like my phone or my laptop, putting for example `192.168.0.79:3000`, I can not do it, I get the screenshot error. I fear that this may cause problems when I put it in production. However accessing from my PC to `localhost:3000` I can see the frontend without any problem.